Migrating spring web mvc from 4.1.x to 6.2.0 and jdk 1.8 to 21
I'm migrating spring frm 4.x to 6.2.0 and jdk 1.8 to 21.
Spring Framework
spring-core - ${spring.version} (6.2.0)
spring-beans - ${spring.version}
spring-context - ${spring.version}
spring-tx - ${spring.version}
spring-context-support - ${spring.version}
spring-test - ${spring.version} (scope: test)
spring-aop - ${spring.version}
spring-jdbc - ${spring.version}
spring-orm - ${spring.version}

Spring Integration
spring-integration-core - ${spring.integration.version} (6.4.0)
spring-integration-jpa - ${spring.integration.version}
spring-integration-amqp - ${spring.integration.version}
spring-integration-stream - ${spring.integration.version}

spring-data-jpa - 3.4.0

Jakarta and Related
jakarta.mail-api - 2.1.3
jakarta.persistence-api - 3.2.0

Angus Mail
angus-mail - 2.0.3 (runtime)
angus-activation - 2.0.2 (runtime)

Hibernate
hibernate-core - ${hibernate.version} (6.6.3.Final)

JDBC and Connection Pooling
c3p0 - ${c3p0.version} (0.9.1.2)
jtds - ${jtds.version} (1.3.0)
JSON
jackson-core-asl - 1.9.13
jackson-mapper-asl - 1.9.13

Logging
commons-logging - 1.1.3 (provided)
slf4j-log4j12 - 1.7.5 (provided)
log4j-slf4j-impl - 2.0-beta9 (provided)
log4j - 1.2.16

Testing
junit - ${junit.version} (4.11, scope: test)

AspectJ
aspectjtools - ${org.aspectj.version} (1.9.22.1)
aspectjrt - ${org.aspectj.version}
aspectjweaver - ${org.aspectj.version}

Time Utilities
joda-time - 2.2
time-utils - 1.2 

Others
commons-lang - 2.6
cglib - ${cglib.version} (3.2.0)

Build Plugin Versions
maven-clean-plugin - 3.4.0
maven-jar-plugin - 3.4.2
maven-compiler-plugin - 3.13.0 (source/target: 21)
maven-war-plugin - 3.4.0
sonar-maven-plugin - 3.9.0.2155
maven-release-plugin - Default config

I have moved all the packages from javax.* to jakarta.* and
even made changes in web.xml file as well.
when deploy the application on tomcat 10.1.33 I'm getting below error.
error log -
              at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:599)
                ... 35 more
        Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration$JerseyWebApplicationInitializer does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void onStartup(jakarta.servlet.ServletContext)' of interface org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer.
                at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4426)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
                ... 36 more

but adding this dependency is resolving the issue org.springframework.boot::spring-boot-autoconfigure but why do we need to add spring boot dependency on top of spring. any suggestions will be very helpful.
